# Can I guess on information requested by pet insurance forms?

Tags: cats, maintenance, insurance

I've recently adopted a found cat. Looking into pet insurance many forms ask for unknown information; e.g. date of birth.  Is it ok to guess such information, should we contact those companies to clarify the situation, or are there specialist insurers / policies aimed at such situations?

**Background on the “Found Cat” situation / why we think it's ok to adopt him.**

My girlfriend and I have been visitted by a cat, which often turns up injured. As its injuries were not being treated we assume that he doesn't have an owner, or his owner's unable to fully care for him. As such we got in touch with a friend who works for a cat charity, who took him to the Celia Hammond Animal Trust to have him looked at. They cleaned him up, confirmed he's been neutered and that he's not chipped. They advised that he's being bullied by unneutered toms in the area, and to try to keep him inside more to keep him safe. As such we're slowly getting him used to staying with us / will wait to see if an owner comes forward in the meantime (though suspect that`s unlikely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in doubt, ask your vet to estimate the critters age. The insurance companies are aware that pets don't usually come with birth certificate, and an informed estimate is acceptable.